# Laravel document root Forbidden with HTTP 403 error

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos7, http-status-code-403

I have laravel instaled CentOS 7 server. PHP, MariaDB and HTTPD are installed and works. All services are up and works. Browse the document root shows

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

this is the document root of my server

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/api/public"
```

Document root configurations

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is welcome.conf file ( /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf)

```
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome" page if there
# is no default index page present for the root URL.  To disable the
# Welcome page, comment out all the lines below.
#
# NOTE: if this file is removed, it will be restored on upgrades.
#
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>

<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

What can I do for this issue?

Comment: replace `<Directory "/var/www/html">` with `<Directory "/var/www/html/api/public">`

Comment: Thanks @rkj Changed the Document root, but issue is still tha same as previouse

Comment: look at this and change accordingly https://gist.github.com/dj1020/e9898200d82ad9a56c84e3cec644b44b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below server configurations are fixed the issue with me.

Grant Folder Permission and Set ownership

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/laravel
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/laravel/storage
```

Restore Security

```
restorecon -R /var/www
```

Disable SELinux

```
setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and put this .htaccess file in your app folder.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```